# File size mismatch

Tags: linux, filesystems

What's the reason behind the difference in reported file sizes?

```
[root@localhost]# ls -lah sendlog
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mail mail 1.3T Aug 15 17:30 sendlog

[root@localhost]# du -m sendlog
24M  sendlog
```

This came to our attention when a server's backup kept failing for quota issues, so it wasn't only "ls" which was seeing this wrong size.

Terms like "sparse files" and "block assignment" are coming to mind, but I'm not sure why it would happen or the real reason behind it. Obviously there is a difference in the ways the two commands check size, am I right always trusting du?

FYI, this should be a pretty standard mail log file.

Comment: Could it be that the file is still being written to? From a Windows perspective, if I am writing to a large file, the Explorer view will show 0 bytes, whereas a tool like Contig will show the true size.

Comment: Could you do show us output of df -k, ls -l sendlog (without -h) and stat sendlog ?

Comment: And the filesystem type please.

Comment: The client has now since removed the file in order to make the backups work again, so I can't get any more information. I shall however keep an eye out for it again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference between the values is as follows.

From the manual of [stat(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat)

```
struct stat {
    // snip
    off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
    // snip
    blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of blocks allocated */
    // snip
};
```

> The st_blocks field indicates the
>   number of blocks allocated to the
>   file, 512-byte units. (This may be
>   smaller than st_size/512, for example,
>   when the file has holes.)

The size as reported by ls is `st_size`, the size as reported by du is `st_blocks * 512`

The value reported by du is the number of bytes used by the file on the filesystem/disk, and the value reported by ls is the actual size/length of the file when you interact with it. (In addition to operating with on-disk usage, du also only counts hardlilnked files once)

Which value is the "right one" depends on context. If you're after disk-usage du is correct, if you're wondering how many bytes is in the file, ls/`st_size` is correct.

In addition, you can by using various options get i.e. du (--apparent-size) to use the size reported by `st_size` or you can get ls (-s) to report the number of blocks used.

Your assumption regarding your logfile beeing a sparse file sounds plausible, however, the reason why I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Just as Kjetil explained, you have a sparse file. Blocks of blank data inside the file are not allocated to disk until you actually write to those blocks. How that happened in a log file is a mystery. You have to check your audit logs from the last time sendlog had a correct size to the time where it had this huge hole. Perhaps the answer is in the log file itself.

Perhaps someone did that intentionally to cause havoc in your system. Or it was some software error.

You can create your own terabyte-sized file easily with:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of='OMG_Thats_a_1_terabyte_file!!.dat' seek=1T bs=1 count=1
```

That file will allocate only a few kilobytes of disk space in any current Linux version with a filesystem with support for sparse files.

Your backup solution needs a replacement. Any serious backup system nowadays handle sparse files efficiently. Even the simplest solution using GNU tar support it (-S or --sparse option).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `du` doesn't support such large numbers?

Comment: Do you really think that he has a log file of 1.3TB ? ..

Comment: It's only a 120GB HDD :)

Answer (score 0):

Your filesystem could be corrupted (or disk has some physical problems). You should do fsck ASAP (on unmounted partition) and see what happens with those numbers afterwards.